# words hyperlink in a wordcloud

Tags: python, hyperlink, word-cloud

i am trying to develop a hyperlink worcloud. MWE is given below, any hint please.

```
link = {'Python':'https://www.python.org/',
        'R':'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/',
        'php':'https://www.php.net/downloads.php',
        'java':'https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp',
        'C++':'https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/'
        }
freq = {'Python':30,
       'R': 17,
       'php':15,
       'java':13,
       'C++':10
       }

wordcloud = WordCloud(colormap='tab10').generate_from_frequencies(freq)
#display
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]